# SQL query duplicated on PHP PDO and different from the result on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

I have duplicated result of the same DB row when I query with PHP PDO and when I execute the same query on phpmyadmin I get 2 distinct rows which is accurate.

I must get the same 2 rows like on phpmyadmin but with pdo, so here is my code and my pdo result:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=mysql;dbname=mydb;charset=utf8mb4', 'root', 'tiger');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $result = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS num_rows FROM `banner`");
    $numRows = $result->fetchColumn();

    if ($numRows > 0) {

    $domain = $_GET['domain']; // URL PARAMETER GOES HERE

    $myQuery = $conn->prepare(
"SELECT * 
    FROM
        banner B 
    JOIN dictionary D
            ON B.dictionaryId = D.id
    WHERE
        B.domains = : domains
        AND B.dictionaryId IS NOT NULL
        AND B.startDate <= NOW ()
        AND B.finishDate >= NOW ()
    ORDER BY
        B.position ASC");
    $myQuery->bindParam(':domains', $domain);
    $myQuery->execute();
    $banner = $myQuery->fetch();
    // echo $banner[14];
    var_dump($banner);
    die;
```

And this is the Results:

> /var/www/html/dropbox_db_connection.php:54: array (size=33)   'id' =>
>   string '1' (length=1)   0 => string '5' (length=1)   'dictionaryId' =>
>   string '1' (length=1)   1 => string '1' (length=1)   'name' => string
>   'blink' (length=5)   2 => string 'blink' (length=5)   'destinationURL'
>   => string 'github.com' (length=10)   3 => string 'github.com' (length=10)   'domains' => string 'github' (length=6)   4 => string
>   'github' (length=6)   'imageURL' => string
>   'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/1/ABimtamHV3_o7EnMC3s5tHpYRwMwS8cyZMtfQGlqpxa6yepgnelceukKJbo9eGONQLquiy-iPAFaeK0NT1cmx0RWGu6Z_DzN0-_FLQAkpeLGm7RAYviP6yfuYvGzE9MR32h2a5OyXjJLskWupTS9bGcZzabicGxmleJeuyiOotBQUkFto3gLGgkNxXd0n1O4DdFkUoN1WB4Jijr2UDLiW3w68lAJVUgRYn3lnN393cwWIYzKEQJiphZXmNCPGXOQp7idyt5ft9aLm6bppw5rxsJDJ2Z9VzSEn1LKXyRBOIPpAf9GDqJL6g2zk-cvw7sRia0'
>   (length=365)   5 => string
>   'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/apitl/1/ABimtamHV3_o7EnMC3s5tHpYRwMwS8cyZMtfQGlqpxa6yepgnelceukKJbo9eGONQLquiy-iPAFaeK0NT1cmx0RWGu6Z_DzN0-_FLQAkpeLGm7RAYviP6yfuYvGzE9MR32h2a5OyXjJLskWupTS9bGcZzabicGxmleJeuyiOotBQUkFto3gLGgkNxXd0n1O4DdFkUoN1WB4Jijr2UDLiW3w68lAJVUgRYn3lnN393cwWIYzKEQJiphZXmNCPGXOQp7idyt5ft9aLm6bppw5rxsJDJ2Z9VzSEn1LKXyRBOIPpAf9GDqJL6g2zk-cvw7sRia0'
>   (length=365)   'position' => string '5' (length=1)   6 => string '5'
>   (length=1)   'startDate' => string '2019-04-18 03:00:00' (length=19)
>   7 => string '2019-04-18 03:00:00' (length=19)   'finishDate' => string
>   '2019-05-04 00:00:00' (length=19)   8 => string '2019-05-04 00:00:00'
>   (length=19)   9 => string '1' (length=1)   'it' => string 'Sed tempus
>   libero a tristique placerat. ' (length=41)   10 => string 'Sed tempus
>   libero a tristique placerat. ' (length=41)   'en' => string 'Curabitur
>   at justo sit amet mi aliquam vestibulum. ' (length=52)   11 => string
>   'Curabitur at justo sit amet mi aliquam vestibulum. ' (length=52)
>   'fr' => string 'Duis sed elit suscipit, venenatis ipsum vitae,
>   molestie elit. ' (length=63)   12 => string 'Duis sed elit suscipit,
>   venenatis ipsum vitae, molestie elit. ' (length=63)   'es' => string
>   'Ut ac tortor semper, finibus est ac, porta erat. ' (length=50)   13
>   => string 'Ut ac tortor semper, finibus est ac, porta erat. ' (length=50)   'pt' => string 'Morbi sit amet quam facilisis, tristique
>   mi a, sagittis quam. ' (length=63)   14 => string 'Morbi sit amet quam
>   facilisis, tristique mi a, sagittis quam. ' (length=63)   'de' =>
>   string 'Nulla nec sem quis velit tristique tempus vel id augue. '
>   (length=57)   15 => string 'Nulla nec sem quis velit tristique tempus
>   vel id augue. ' (length=57)   'nl' => string 'Mauris tincidunt leo
>   eget tincidunt bibendum. ' (length=47)   16 => string 'Mauris
>   tincidunt leo eget tincidunt bibendum. ' (length=47)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems, the first which is the row being duplicated, this is down to `fetch()` defaulting to `FETCH_BOTH`, which means it will return both an associative set of data as well as a numerically indexed set of data (both with the same values).  I usually use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` as this is just values indexed by column names.

The second is that you only retrieve 1 row, the call to `fetch()` would normally be in a loop...

```
$myQuery->execute();
while( $banner = $myQuery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // echo $banner['pt'];
    var_dump($banner);
}
```

or set the default mode for fetch using

```
$connection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Do this just after making the connection so that all calls to `fetch()` will give the same style.